# Не отображается редактор Markdown в браузере Chrome последней версии

Tags: дефект, статус-не-воспроизводится, дизайн

Почему не показывает редактор Markdown в браузере Chrome 51.0.2704.103 версии?

> [image: редактор markdown]

Ошибка консоли неработающего браузера совпадают с ошибками работающего:

> b.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>   https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
>   http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/wmd.ru.js?v=90bcfd3b7d03 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 499 (Request has been forbidden by antivirus)

Comment: В какой конкретно версии?

Comment: @Nofate Версия 51.0.2704.103 m

Comment: @Nofate проверил у себя: версия Chrome: **Версия 51.0.2704.103 m**, все отображается, Chrome обновился до версии **52.0.2743.82 m** так же все нормально

Comment: @Nofate да я тоже проверял на разных версиях. видимо глюк какого то плагина. а на этом компе нет админских прав переустанавливать хром

Comment: посмотри ошибки в консоли

Comment: Если есть юзерскрипты (вроде *monkey), отключите их и проверьте снова.

Comment: @Grundy в логах ошибки нет

Comment: А на другой машине воспроизводится? И попробуйте почистить кэш.

Comment: @VladD почистил все за все время - не помогло. осталось пробовать сброс настроек, но это уже в последнюю очередь

Comment: @SeniorAutomator Можно просто создать отдельный пустой профиль.

Comment: http или https? Нажми в браузере F12, и обнови страницу. Ошибки в консоли есть?

Comment: @Qwertiy обновил вопрос. см выше

Comment: _"Request has been forbidden by antivirus"_ - хм))

Comment: @Qwertiy упс. что то не заметил